# C# importing C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, function, dll, import

I have a managed dll file which imports functions from a C++ dll to the managed environment. I'm using some of its functions in my program but the problem is, I get this error when I use it:

Unable to load DLL 'Libraries\lib.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I placed the .dll file in the program's directory and in the system32 folder. However, it still doesn't work. I think I have to use DLLImport but I have no idea how to use it.. even after looking at some examples I am still confused. Can someone help me here?

Comment: Mind telling me what details you need?

Comment: Names of DLLs. Where they are located. The DLLImport statement.

Comment: @David, some code would help.

Comment: @Ben Well, that's why I want to see the DLLimport statement.

Comment: @David Heffernan, my first comment was aimed at the op

Comment: The problem is I don't have any DLLImport code, nor I do understand how it works which is why I asked here. Also, the name of the .dll file is lib.dll, and I've placed it in the program's directory/system 32 folder and several other folders but I still got that error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say:

> I placed the .dll file in the program's directory...

But:

> Unable to load DLL **'Libraries\lib.dll'**

We need to see your `DLLImport` attribute creation, i.e., the C# signature of the native method.  It looks to me like you probably specify the path, i.e.,

```
[DllImport( "Libraries\lib.dll" )];
static extern void MyNativeMethod();
```

Try using this instead:

```
[DllImport( "lib.dll" )];
static extern void MyNativeMethod();
```

That will search the running directory as well as through your `PATH` environment variable.  If you specify a file path as you do I honestly don't know if it will search through `PATH` if the file is not found (I couldn't find mention of it in [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't enough information here to help, as you're not showing the API (in native code) you're trying to import, etc.

That being said, I'd strongly recommend reading the [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as well as [A Closer Look at Platform Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719485%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN.  They walk through the main issues, as well as showing many examples of how to import and use functions from a C++ DLL.

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way of using a c++ dll file in c# :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace demo1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("shi.dll", EntryPoint = "?HelloWorld@@YAXXZ")]
       public static extern int HelloWorld();
      public  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(StringUtilities.HelloWorld());
            Console.WriteLine(HelloWorld());
            // public static extern void HelloWorld();
           //  HelloWorld();
            //  Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of the exports (use [dependancy walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check) and that you have correctly mapped them using the correct PInvoke calls, then your issue might be 32/64 bit related especially if you are on a 64bit OS with a .NET application set to Any CPU.

A 32 bit native DLL can only be loaded by a 32 bit .NET process when using PInvoke (the same applies to 64 bit native DLLs).

You can change the platform target using Properties->Build->Platform target or you can use the [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699.aspx) utility.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with different .dll file , the solution was to change the target to x64 instead of x86