# how to integrate { opencv c++ } code in a mobile app developed in unity 3D with c#

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, unity-game-engine, integration

I have created a program in c++ and OPENCV 
which performs various computer vision tasks.

Now I want to use that program or its function {which one is easy} in my android app which I'm creating in unity-3d with c#

I want to know how I can use opencv functions with c++ in a unity3d app with c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a DLL from your c++ program and then import that DLL in you c# project like described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232259/c-sharp-importing-c-dll).